# Accesing second element of list for every list in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of lists, all of them have the same length. For example:

```
a <- list(list(1,2), list(4,8), list(0,1))
```

I need to access the second element of every list in this list. In this example it would be equivalent to using a matrix and using

```
a[ , 2]
```

But I need to work with lists.

Comment: `lapply(a, function(x) x[[2]])`

Comment: Or equivalently, `lapply(a, "[[", 2)`